# How can I use a helper path inside of a form_for tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, action, form-for

I have two view files that can log someone in. One is a new.html.erb file inside of users, and this makes an entirely new user and logs them in. On the login page, I have a form that begins with `<%= form_for @user ... %>` but when that's submitted it will have a route request of "POST /users". I want it to either "POST /signin" or at least I want to fit `signin_path` inside the form, but I don't know where or how

Comment: Try using `form_with` if you're on a relatively modern version of rails: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with the syntax is much easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can send a url parameter and a method parameter, with the `signin_path` and the method `Post` in your `form_for`.

```
<%= form_for @user, url: signin_path, method: :post do |f| %>
```